# Linear transformation on a complex vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I am going through *Linear Algebra Done Wrong*, and I am not sure about my answer to one of the exercises.

This is the question:

"The set $\mathbb{C}$ of complex numbers can be canonically identified with the space $\mathbb{R}^2$ by treating each $z=x+iy \in \mathbb{C}$ as $(x,y)^T \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

a) Treating $\mathbb{C}$ as a complex vector space, show that the multiplication by $\alpha = a+ib \in \mathbb{C}$ is a linear transformation. What is its matrix?

b) Treating $\mathbb{C}$ as the real vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$, show that the multiplication by $\alpha = a+ib$ defines a linear transformation there. What is its matrix?"

For the first question, I showed that it is a linear transformation. To find its matrix, I first need a basis. But since this is a complex vector space, all the scalars are complex numbers so $\mathbf{1}$ is a basis because for any $\mathbf{z} \in \mathbb{C}$, $\mathbf{z} = z\mathbf{1}$  . The image of $\mathbf{1}$ is $\mathbf{\alpha}$, since $\mathbf{1}$ is the multiplicative neutral element. So, the matrix is simply $(\mathbf{\alpha})$.

To check, for any $\mathbf{z} \in \mathbb{C}$, $T(\mathbf{z})=(\mathbf{\alpha}) (z) =  \alpha \mathbf{z}$, which is the described linear transformation.

For the second question, to find its matrix, I took $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ as the basis. Multiplying by $\alpha$, I found the matrix to be

$$\begin{pmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a\end{pmatrix}.$$

Are these solutions correct? I am mainly confused by the first example. Whenever we take the scalar multiplication to be the "ordinary multiplication", it gets confusing because the definition of ordinary multiplication is a bit muddy for me. The book that I'm using (or any other book that I'm aware of) doesn't define it and just assumes familiarity. However, when we are investigating the properties of multiplication, not having a clear definition makes it a bit difficult.

Comment: Your solutions are quite fine. Note the ùmatrix  for the first case would be the same in any field.

Comment: The definition of comples multiplication is simple. It is just $$(a + bi)(c + di) = (ac - bd) + (ad + bc)i$$If you want the definition of real multiplication, that's a bit more complicated, because you start with positive integers (repeated addition), then extend to positive rationals ($\frac ab\frac cd = \frac {ab}{cd}$), then to positive reals ($ab =\sup \{pq\mid 0 < p,q \in \Bbb Q, p < a, q < b\}$) and finally to $0$ (you know it) and negatives ($(-a)b = -(ab)$). Of course many variations are possible.